# How to put one direct speech into another direct speech?

Tags: grammar

I am writing a letter. a piece of that, is as follows:

My grandson’s class mate told:

> “When I was a little boy I had a broken donkey doll. I loved that, but one day my mother discarded it. When I noticed, I began to cry. The day after that the phone rang, and my mother picked it up. She told me “Come on, the ghost of that donkey wants to talk with you.” Then I heard “ I am the ghost of that donkey. Now I am in heaven. Here is very good place and I am so happy. Blah, blah, blah” This made me calm. When I became older I understood that the ghost of my donkey doll was my father.”

As you can see I have to use direct speech into a bigger direct speech. So did I do that correctly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done by putting double quotes around the large quoted section with single quotes around the smaller inner section. You example would be written:

> “When I was a little boy I had a broken donkey doll. I loved that, but one day my mother discarded it. When I noticed, I began to cry. The day after that the phone rang, and my mother picked it up. She told me ‘Come on, the ghost of that donkey wants to talk with you.’ Then I heard ‘I am the ghost of that donkey. Now I am in heaven. Here is very good place and I am so happy. Blah, blah, blah’ This made me calm. When I became older I understood that the ghost of my donkey doll was my father.”